# Как в цикле обозначить из списка значения None другим

Tags: python

Я знаю что возможно уже есть где-то решение, но я не нашёл.

У меня есть список , пример:

```
(None, 'Дмитрий', 'Renault Duster 2020', 'AA1111AA')
('Москва', 'Сергей', 'Opel Zafira 2009', 'А999ААА777')
('Пермь', 'Александр', 'BMW 318 2011', None)
```

У меня есть строка кода которая обрабатывает этот лист, но иногда попадаются None и это мешает читабельности.

Мне бы хотелось там где None заменить на, допустим, не найдено, а вообще лучше убрать ту строку, вот пример моего кода (возможно ударит по глазам):

```
        city = ''
        name = ''
        marka = ''
        carnumber = ''
        for item in rows:
            city += '\nГород: '+str(item[0])
            name += '\nИмя: '+str(item[1])
            marka +=  '\nМарка машины: '+str(item[2])
            carnumber += '\nГос.Номер машины: '+str(item[3])
        final_str = city + name + marka + carnumber
```

Получится результат на примере первой стоки листа:

```
Город: None
Имя: Дмитрий
Марка машины: Renault Duster 2020
Гос.номер машины: AA1111AA
```

Мне бы хотелось убрать строку которая содержит None, как это можно сделать более менее нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

data = [
    (None, 'Дмитрий', 'Renault Duster 2020', 'AA1111AA'),
    ('Москва', 'Сергей', 'Opel Zafira 2009', 'А999ААА777'),
    ('Пермь', 'Александр', 'BMW 318 2011', None),
]
ks = ['Город', 'Имя', 'Марка машины', 'Гос.номер машины']


dt = dict(zip(ks, data[0]))
print(json.dumps(dt, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
```

> ```
> {
>   "Город": null,
>   "Имя": "Дмитрий",
>   "Марка машины": "Renault Duster 2020",
>   "Гос.номер машины": "AA1111AA"
> }
> ```

```
dt = {k: d for k, d in zip(ks, data[0]) if d}
print(json.dumps(dt, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
```

> ```
> {
>   "Имя": "Дмитрий",
>   "Марка машины": "Renault Duster 2020",
>   "Гос.номер машины": "AA1111AA"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

например такой код оставит только те данные, где нет None:

```
rows = [(None, 'Дмитрий', 'Renault Duster 2020', 'AA1111AA'),
        ('Москва', 'Сергей', 'Opel Zafira 2009', 'А999ААА777'),
        ('Пермь', 'Александр', 'BMW 318 2011', None)]

for row in filter(lambda obj: all(map(lambda elem: elem is not None, obj)), rows):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Так то да, но при обработке в цикле если не будет одной колонки выдаст ошибку index out of range, это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Я это сделал по другому, просто взял и в цикле начал проверку на if item[0] is None и так далее, конечно получается говно-код но по-другому без использования других библиотек я не знаю как